# How do I force an iOS app make a network call every second?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, network-programming

We need that the iOS app should make a network call to our server every second to see if there any new data. Will this cause the app to eventually crash?

How bad is it? Could a possible solution be to just have one View Controller do this... therefore while on just this screen, a network call is being made every second?

I know that another solution is to use GCM, but it is too late for that.

Comment: Every second....  I doubt network traffic would allow you to do it.

Comment: Having such app is really stupid idea, the phone battery wouldn't last 5 minutes.

Comment: The WWDC Session Writing Energy Efficient Apps
 (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/238/) explains why that is a horrible idea. Show that to your boss.

Comment: It's a terrible idea. The app itself will be very energy inefficient and you'd basically be selling a self DDOS botnet. Imagine 10,000 people download and install your app and each one pings your server every second. Are you confident your server can handle the load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't use APNs. if server data is changed, you can send APNs to your app and then refresh your data on your phone.

here is site that you can get helps.

[APNs Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1)

[push-notifications-tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: Much better approach, since having application refreshing data all the time is really not effective.